# serverless custom authorizer denying authorization

Tags: authorization, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm building an api with serverless and a custom authorizer on api-gateway. When running serverless-local and passing a valid authorization token, I'm getting 401 responses.

I've mostly copied this from examples, the function which is called by the authorizer is

```
var apiGatewayAuth = function(event, context, callback) {
    if(event.authorizationToken == 'undefined'){
      return callback(null,generatePolicy('', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
    }
    var token = validateToken(event.authorizationToken);
    if (token.error) {
      return callback(null, generatePolicy('', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
    } 
    console.log('allow',generatePolicy(token.sub, 'Allow', event.methodArn))
    return callback(null,generatePolicy(token.sub, 'Allow', event.methodArn));
};
```

The policy is generated via

```
var generatePolicy = function(accountId, effect, resource) {
  var authResponse = {};
  authResponse.principalId = accountId;
  if (effect && resource) {
    var policyDocument = {};
    policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17';
    policyDocument.Statement = [];
    var statementOne = {};
    statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke';
    statementOne.Effect = effect;
    statementOne.Resource = resource;
    policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
    authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
  }
  return authResponse;
};
```

The returned policy looks like

```
{ principalId: 'test_api_user',
  policyDocument: { 
     Version: '2012-10-17',
     Statement: [ { Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
    Effect: 'Allow',
    Resource: 'my:arn' } ]
}
```

Is there something I am obviously doing wrong here?

My `token.sub` is a string of unique user name for my app, but AWS has no concept of who the user is, I thought this was fine.

Comment: Does it work with * Resource?

Comment: @AbhignaNagaraja I think you mean changing `statementOne.Resource = "*"` - yes that works.. so the issue is with my arn? Any idea how to further debug?

Comment: @AbhignaNagaraja thanks for your help, it turns out is was how I was setting up the ARN role. I've got it sorted now.

Comment: Can you expand on the setting up ARN role thing? Im running into the same problem. I can see from lambda logs that the policy returned is correct but it keeps giving 403 user not authorized to access. Thanks!

Comment: @pedalpete Can you post the answer?